# Problem with borders when resizing the height of EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm developing an Android app targeting Android 2.3 (API9).

I want to resize the height of a simple `EditText` but when I set `android:layout_height="10pt"` the border of the `EditText` becomes dislocated.

The problem is shown here

[image]

I tried layout_height, height, textsize.. pt, px, sp... but the same problem.

I haven't tried the application on real device yet.

Answer (score 1):

What layout contains the `EdiText`?  You should never use exact pixel sizes when configuring items in Android, since your layout needs to work properly at many different screen sizes and densities.  (See [supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for details).

If you really want a specific size, us dp for density independent pixels.  It should work to set the `layout_height="10dp"`  However, that won't increase the size of the text within the EditText.  You need to use `textSize` for that.  You are probably better off setting `textSize` and setting the `layout_height="wrap_content"`.

See this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696245/android-how-to-change-the-textsize-in-an-edittext-field) about the extra line.  It looks like setting a background color might fix that.

Comment: I have this xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <EditText android:text="@+id/EditText01" android:id="@+id/EditText01"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="5dp"
  android:textSize="3dip" />

</LinearLayout> 
but the same problem with the border.

I tried layout_height: wrap_content .. but this does not change the height of the EditBox.

Stanislav

Comment: Did you set the background color as suggested?

Comment: Also, a text size of 3dp is very small.  If you set it higher, you should see the size of the EditText increase.

Comment: Mayra thanks for your quick reply! If I set the  bg of the EditText =WHITE.. I don't see any borders

Comment: How can I set the borders this way?

Comment: I think you might need to use a custom background using the 9 patch tool, which allows for a background image that stretches: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Comment: Mayra, 10x. It's ok if I user custom background IMAGE.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same sort of problem (and it's a real pain). With some experimentation I have found that if you use "dp" and apply this rule of thumb, it should work for EditText fields.

textSize x 3= layout_height

I say rule of thumb because the minimum height before the field "breaks" again is about 29dp. So, for example if you have textSize="10dp", then layout_height="30dp", or textSize="12dp", then layout_height="36dp". You can have smaller textSizes, but it becomes illegible lower than 9dp. I found this works well in relative_layouts with default fonts. Good luck!